# How to sorting parent and child CoreData element in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, higher-order-functions

I have 3 entity in my CoreData model.Category ,Subcategory ,inventory.inventory connected to subcategory and subcategory connected to category using relationships.so when I want to get inventory and subcategory than I get using category data.so my problem is I want to sorting all three entity data using alphabetical order.

```
class func getAllCategoriesObject() -> [DBCategories]?
    {
        let context = getContext()

        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<DBCategories> = DBCategories.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do{
            let fetchedData = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).sorted(by: { (objCategory1, objCategory2) -> Bool in
                (objCategory1.subcategories?.allObjects as? [DBSubCategories] ?? []).sorted { (objSubCategory1, objSubCategory2) -> Bool in

                    (objSubCategory1.inventories?.allObjects as? [DBInventories] ?? []).sorted { (objInventory1, objInventory2) -> Bool in

                        return objInventory1.title?.capitalized ?? "" < objInventory2.title?.capitalized ?? ""
                    }

                    return objSubCategory1.title?.capitalized ?? "" < objSubCategory2.title?.capitalized ?? ""
                }

                return objCategory1.title?.capitalized ?? "" < objCategory2.title?.capitalized ?? ""
            })



            return fetchedData
        }
        catch
        {
            print( error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return []
    }
```

I had tried above code but not getting output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that - you're not allowed to sort Core Data relationships with sort blocks.
If you want to achieve alphabetical order, you can do it with:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: [KEY NAME], ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
```

**If you wish to do in one fetch** then you must make sure the Core Data objects are already sorted when you save them - by using an ordered relationship (you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/configuring_relationships)).
So when you fetch the parent object the child object connected with the NSOrderedSet relationship are already sorted according to you wishes.

Just for quick example:

```
//Create context, create objects in context
let someChildsObject: [NSManagedObject] = //.. Objects with name property
someChildsObject.sorted(by: { $0.name > $1.name }) //Sorting according to name value
parent.children = NSOrderedSet(array: someChildsObject)
//Save context
```

By Doing so the data will be already sorted in the database.